# django.db.utils.operationalerror unable to open database file

Tags: html, django, database, ubuntu

I have been struggling finding a solution to my issue

> django.db.utils.operationalerror unable to open database file.

I have changed permissions and set my path to an absolute one yet still have the same error.

this is my settings.py file

```
"""
Django settings for bastionblog project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
from main import constants

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATES_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = constants.SECRET_KEY

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['77.68.125.183']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'bastionblog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIRS],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'bastionblog.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': constants.ENGINE,
        'NAME': constants.NAME, 
        'USER': constants.USER,
        'PASSWORD': constants.DB_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': constants.ENGINE,
        'PORT': constants.PORT,
    }
}




# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = ((os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')), )

STATIC_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

this is my constants.py file (imports sensitive variables)

```
ENGINE = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'

NAME = '/var/lib/mysql/bastionblog'

USER = 'admin'

PORT = '3306'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access a MySQL database with the SQLite driver.

To use the MySQL driver:

`pip install mysqlclient`

Then in your settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {  
    'default': {  
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  
        'NAME': 'your_database_name',  
        'USER': 'your_database_user',  
        'PASSWORD': 'your_password',  
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',  
        'PORT': '3306',  
    }  
}
```

Also, `NAME = '/var/lib/mysql/bastionblog'` is wrong. You don't need to enter a path, just the database name.